How can I set nvim-tree to default to opening the current directory instead of the main directory?
[open nvim-tree shows] (https://i.sstatic.net/54qS6.png)
I tried to add open_on_setup_files in nvim_tree.setup(), but it prop Unknown.
here is my code of nvim-tree.lua
local status, nvim_tree = pcall(require, "nvim-tree")
if not status then
    vim.notify("没有找到 nvim-tree")
  return
end

-- 列表操作快捷键
local list_keys = require('keybindings').nvimTreeList
nvim_tree.setup({
    -- 不显示 git 状态图标
    git = {
        enable = false,
    },
    -- project plugin 需要这样设置
    update_cwd = true,
    update_focused_file = {
        enable = true,
        update_cwd = true,
    },
    -- 隐藏 .文件 和 node_modules 文件夹
    filters = {
        dotfiles = true,
        custom = { 'node_modules' },
    },
    view = {
        -- 宽度
        width = 35,
        -- 也可以 'right'
        side = 'left',
        -- 隐藏根目录
        -- hide_root_folder = false,
        -- 显示行数
        number = true,
        relativenumber = true,
        -- 显示图标
        signcolumn = 'yes',
    },
    --on_attach = {
        --custom_only = false,
        --list = list_keys,
    --},
    actions = {
        open_file = {
            -- 首次打开大小适配
            resize_window = true,
            -- 打开文件时关闭
            quit_on_open = true,
        },
    },
})
-- 自动关闭
vim.cmd([[
  autocmd BufEnter * ++nested if winnr('$') == 1 && bufname() == 'NvimTree_' . tabpagenr() | quit | endif
]])

I searched github to get answer, but I can`t get what i want.
